# Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch

Tags: meaning, british-english

What does mean by Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch ? I found this word as largest word in the world

Comment: It's Welsh, not English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Welsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the name of a town in Wales, an artificial name invented in the 19th century to attract tourists.

'Llanfair Pwllgwyngyl' means 'St. Mary's Church in Whitehollow', Pwllgwygyl being the town's original name. The rest of the name means 'near the rapid whirlpool of St. Tysilio's Church with the red cave'.

The longest word ever to appear in literature appears to be *Lopado­­temacho­­selacho­­galeo­­kranio­­leipsano­­drim­­hypo­­trimmato­­silphio­­parao­­melito­­katakechy­­meno­­kichl­­epi­­kossypho­­phatto­­perister­­alektryon­­opte­­kephallio­­kigklo­­peleio­­lagoio­­siraio­­baphe­­tragano­­pterygon*, from Aristophanes' 391 BC play *Ecclesiazusae*.

You can look up both these words on Wikipedia.

Comment: Here's a song to teach you how to pronounce it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BXKsQ2nbno